# Embedding <script> tag for Neatcal on Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I would like to embed this code on my Gatsby site, what would be the best practice? I'm still learning and any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

```
<script 
            id="nc-booking-widget-script" 
            src="https://www.neatcal.com/app/services/booking/assets/js/integrate.js?v=21.04.26.5" 
            data-access-key="fcd3a2ae209d9ccae0d5fb3e66e9dabc" 
            data-nc-root="https://www.neatcal.com/app" 
            data-booking-url="https://www.neatcal.com/app/services/booking/book?u=fcd3a2ae209d9ccae0d5fb3e66e9dabc&widget_order=all_services,time&photo_mode=0&click_and_go=1&class_list_tmpl=list-1"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and native approach, not only in Gatsby, but generally in React is using the [`Helmet` component](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). Basically, whatever is wrapped inside this component is outputted in the `<head>` tag, no matter the original component.

To use it, just install (via `yarn add react-helmet` or `npm install --save react-helmet`)  it and use like:

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

const HomePage = (props)=> {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://someSite.net/example" />
                <script id="nc-booking-widget-script" src="https://www.neatcal.com/app/services/booking/assets/js/integrate.js?v=21.04.26.5" data-access-key="fcd3a2ae209d9ccae0d5fb3e66e9dabc" data-nc-root="https://www.neatcal.com/app"  data-booking-url="https://www.neatcal.com/app/services/booking/book?u=fcd3a2ae209d9ccae0d5fb3e66e9dabc&widget_order=all_services,time&photo_mode=0&click_and_go=1&class_list_tmpl=list-1"/>
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

In Gatsby, in addition, you can [customize the resultant HTML](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/) (created once build) by:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

This will copy the `default-html.js` file from `.cache` to `src/html.js`. There, you can embed your script like:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        <script
          id="nc-booking-widget-script"
          src="https://www.neatcal.com/app/services/booking/assets/js/integrate.js?v=21.04.26.5"
          data-access-key="fcd3a2ae209d9ccae0d5fb3e66e9dabc"
          data-nc-root="https://www.neatcal.com/app"
          data-booking-url="https://www.neatcal.com/app/services/booking/book?u=fcd3a2ae209d9ccae0d5fb3e66e9dabc&widget_order=all_services,time&photo_mode=0&click_and_go=1&class_list_tmpl=list-1"></script>
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

Both are valid and cleanest approaches.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will give it a try!